# How to import an existing code in eclipse from a zip file?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project called MathOps in a zip file and want to import it in eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start Eclipse, go to File->Import->General->Existing Projects Into Workspace
Select the archive file option, and browse to the downloaded zip file and click Finish.
This will create a project named MathOps in your workspace (Take care that you don’t have
any project by that name in your workspace from earlier).